# What are all pairs $(R,M)$ of a ring $R$ and a two-sided $R$-module $M$ such that all endomorphisms of $M$ are scalar multiples of $\text{id}_M$?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-rings

I was playing with some endomorphism rings and got curious whether there is a classification of all ***two-sided*** (not necessarily unitary on any side) modules $M$ over a (not necessarily unital) ring $R$ such that for every ***right*** $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi:M\to M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $$\varphi(x)=r\cdot x$$ for all $x\in M$.  I know that it means $$\text{End}_R(M)\cong R/\text{Ann}_R(M)$$ but I can't make any interesting conclusion from this.  Here $$\text{Ann}_R(M):=\Big\{r\in R\,\Big|\,r\cdot x=0\text{ for every }x\in M\Big\}$$ is the ***left*** annihilator of $M$.

In the case that  $R$ is a division ring and $M$ is an $R$-vector space, then it is obvious that $M$ must be at most one-dimensional.  Could you please give me some references if there are any studies regarding this question?

**Edit:**  I made an error, which has been fixed.  I originally said that $M$ was a ***left*** $R$-module, which would make no sense if $R$ is non-commutative.

Comment: In the context of commutative domains, ideals whose endomorphism rings are isomorphic to the domain are called *Archimedean* (E. Matlis, Injective modules over Prüfer rings, Nagoya Math. J. 15 (1959) 57–69.)